# How can I keep a Heroku Node.js instance running indefinitely?

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase, twilio

I've written a simple Node server, deployed on Heroku, that connects to a Firebase DB written to by users of an app of mine.  The server monitors child changes, sending me a message via Twilio when there's new data I need to review.  There's no front end, nor does there need to be.  How can I have Heroku, which ordinarily terminates idle dynos, run this indefinitely so that I can have it monitor Firebase and pass on alerts?

Comment: There are lots of hosting services out there.  Probably too many to mention.  It's common for people to also use firebase-queue to do the kind of thing you're talking about. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Heroku free web dynos that receive no traffic in a 30 minute period will sleep](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping). That prevents the Firebase node.js child_changed listeners from staying active and thus you won't receive the Twilio messages. To prevent that from happening, you can include a very simple setInterval function (like the example in [this article](https://quickleft.com/blog/6-easy-ways-to-prevent-your-heroku-node-app-from-sleeping/)) to run at some frequency less than 30 minutes.

```
var http = require("http");
  setInterval(function() {
    http.get("http://<your app name>.herokuapp.com");
}, 300000); // every 5 minutes (300000)
```

So for a long-term strategy I don't see anything wrong with it.

In case something causes your node.js server to crash, you can also include code to notify yourself something needs to be checked:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  twilioClient.messages.create({...}, function(twilioErr, message) {
    if (twilioErr) {
      console.log("twilio error: " + twilioErr);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  I'd just note that I changed setInterval to setTimeout, because I had problems with each page load spawning a new recurring page-loader, multiplying until I started getting Heroku errors.